# Java: check if logger is empty so it does not creat a txt file

Tags: java, logging, filehandler

I have a class named Logg. That i use for send every exception or other warnings. 
before it creates a file, I want to check if it has anything to write to the file. So it does not create a empty txt file.

code:

```
 package ast;
 /**
 *Handles logging
 * Configured from the config.property file at resources
 */

public class Logg {
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logg.class.getName());
private static FileHandler fh = null;

/**
 * Checks parameter Savemethod gets from config file
 * and what logging Level you have chosen
 *
 * @param saveMethod
 * @param Logg       Level
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void init() throws IOException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = Logg.class.getResourceAsStream("loggconfig");
    if (in != null) {
        prop.load(in);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + in + "' not found in the classpath");
    }

    int saveMethod = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("Savemethod"));

    if(saveMethod == 1){

        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(handler);

    }
    //Creates and Names the logg file to current date
    else if (saveMethod == 2) {
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");
            fh = new FileHandler((dateFormat.format(date) + ".log"), false);
            Logger l = Logger.getLogger("");
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            l.addHandler(fh);

            l.setLevel(Level.parse(prop.getProperty("Level")));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Error in Logg", e);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by installing a proxy handler on the root logger to lazily run your logging config.  The proxy handler level must be the same level as your FileHandler.  Your FileHandler will only get created if something is published to the proxy handler.  Here is some example code:

```
     public class ConfigHandler extends Handler {

        private FileHandler fh;
        private ConsoleHandler ch;

        public ConfigHandler() {
            String p = getClass().getName();
            LogManager m = LogManager.getLogManager();
            try {
                String s = m.getProperty(p + ".level");
                if (s != null) {
                    super.setLevel(Level.parse(s));
                }                
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                super.reportError("", re, ErrorManager.OPEN_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
            try {
                init(record);
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                reportError(null, re, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reportError(null, e, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
            }

            Handler h = this.ch;
            if (h != null) {
                h.publish(record);
            }

            h = this.fh;
            if (h != null) {
                h.publish(record);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void flush() {
            Handler h = this.ch;
            if (h != null) {
                h.flush();
            }

            h = this.fh;
            if (h != null) {
                h.flush();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() throws SecurityException {
            super.setLevel(Level.OFF);
            Handler h = this.ch;
            if (h != null) {
                h.close();
            }

            h = this.fh;
            if (h != null) {
                h.close();
            }
        }

        private boolean allowConsole(LogRecord r) {
            return isLoggable(r);
        }

        private boolean allowFile(LogRecord r) {
            return isLoggable(r);
        }

        private void init(LogRecord r) throws IOException {
            assert Thread.holdsLock(this) : this;
            if (ch != null && fh != null) {
                return;
            }

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream in = ConfigHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("loggconfig");
            if (in != null) {
                prop.load(in);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + in + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            int saveMethod = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("Savemethod"));

            if (saveMethod == 1) {
                if (ch == null && allowConsole(r)) {
                    ch = new ConsoleHandler();
                    ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
                    ch.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
                }
            } //Creates and Names the logg file to current date
            else if (saveMethod == 2) {
                try {
                    if (fh == null && allowFile(r)) {
                        Date date = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");
                        fh = new FileHandler((dateFormat.format(date) + ".log"), false);
                        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
                    }
                    Logger l = Logger.getLogger(""); //???
                    l.setLevel(Level.parse(prop.getProperty("Level")));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    reportError(null, e, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to modify your startup code to manually install this on the root logger or you have to create a logging.properties file to install this handler.  As in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new ConfigHandler());
}
```

Comment: okey, I will try it tomorrow and se if it works! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: what should I modify? Can't get the code to work, dont understand what you meen with "modify your startup code to manually install this on the root logger or you have to create a logging.properties file to install this handler."

Comment: It creates new file every time i run your code as Logg class. I think i doing something wrong or maybe your code?

Comment: The file is created when the FileHandler is created.  The current code uses this.isLoggable to determine if the FileHandler is created.  You either have to raise the level of ConfigHandler or modify the code to meet your needs.

Comment: Okey! I think i'm near to fix it now.. But it does not creating any txt files any more

Comment: got this error message: java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.logging.Level.parse(Level.java:361)
 at ast.ConfigHandler.<init>(ConfigHandler.java:21)

Comment: LogManager.getProperty can return null.  I updated the code example with the fix.

Comment: thank you so much for the help! But the code doesnt make any file.

Comment: Did you prove the FileHandler was created.

Comment: what? it creates a filehandler but it does not creating a file. :S

Comment: feels like it does not read from the property file at all. feels like it would be much more easier to code that i want then this.

Comment: it works now. hehe! But if I set logg level to WARNING, and a exception i've as INFO it still get logged. It only looking if it's null. Can i do a operator that look if the logg level from property file are the same as the exception=